# Past Perfect or Past Simple with the day before

Tags: reported-speech

I have a problem with this question:

> Steve __________ to the manager after lunch the day before.
>   A. spoke
>   B. was speaking
>   C. had spoken
>   D. has spoken

If I have a sentence like the following one, I have to use *had done* for the verb used in **Past Simple**.

> Steve spoke to the manager after lunch yesterday.

So, I will have a new one with **Reported Statements**:

> Steve had spoken to the manager after lunch the day before.

However, as far as I have checked the meanings of each choice, I think there is no other verb used in past simple form like *He said that* so I don't think *had spoken* is a good choice. For me, this one is better:

> Steve spoke to the manager after lunch the day before.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The are all correct depending on the context and following statements.

> Steve spoke to the manager after lunch the day before.  I don't know what it was about.
>
> Steve was speaking to the manager after lunch the day before.  He looked a little upset.
>
> Steve had spoken to the manager after lunch the day before.  He said this wouldn't be a problem anymore.
>
> Steve has spoken to the manager.  It was after lunch the day before.  You don't need to again.  (Not the exact sentence).

Comment: Oh my god. I have never thought that _Past Continuous_ can apply in this situation. One more question, what are the differences between the first and  the third sentences? Is this okay if I don't use _He said that_ before or after _Steve had spoken to..._?

Comment: The implication in #3 is that Steve is speaking to the manager again.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the point. For me, I only use _Past Perfect_ when I think there is another verb used in _Past Simple_ in the sentence.

Comment: What this points up is that _the choice of past verb form in English does not necessarily correlate with an objective difference in the facts_. Often, several different verb forms are possible to describe **exactly the same events**, the difference being in how the speaker is constructing the narrative and what point of time they are focusing on.